# Converting date to Carbon format to apply Add/Sub days in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The format of `$day` variable as follows :

```
"2019-10-30 18:29:19"
```

I'm trying to subtract 1 day as follows :

```
$prv_day = $day->subDays(1);
```

I receive this error :

```
Call to a member function subDays() on a non-object
```

How do I convert this $day format to the `Carbon::now();` format in order to be able to apply `subDays()` to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a straight-forward format, so this will work:

```
$day = '2019-10-30 18:29:19';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $day);
$date->subDay(); // Subtracts 1 day
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

RESULT

```
2019-10-29 06:29:19
```